# Get co-ordinates, height and width of currently visible image in imageview

Tags: android, image, rect

I have implemented a custom image view that allows for pinch zooming and panning of an image. i need to store the co-ordinates of the image and the scale so it can be reproduced on other platforms without saving a new image

```
final TouchImageView imgView = new TouchImageView(this);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.an_img);
final float [] values = new float[9];
img.matrix.getValues(values);

float transX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
float transY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

Log.d("TAG", transX + " : " + transY);
```

/

```
RectF rect = new RectF();
img.matrix.mapRect(rect);
Log.e("RECT::::: ", rect.height() + " : " + rect.width());
```

[image]

co-ordinates within the image of the view-able section of the image (the point in the circle on the left of my drawing)

Comment: did you play with `Matrix#mapPoints` ?

Comment: @pskink no yet. i will look at it now

Comment: i am not 100% sure what point you really need but try to mapPoints[0, 0]

Comment: don't think this will work 0,0 would be the top left of the entire image and not just the view able area

Comment: so what are you getting for `float[] pts = {0, 0}` ? try it with "normal" and `invert()`ed `Matrix`

Comment: sorry. I was printing out the wrong thing. that does appear to work for getting the point in the top left of the view-able area (in negative values). Just need to get the visible width and height now

Comment: Any update? I am struggling with it.

Comment: @TechNikh this question is almost 3 years old so im not sure this is still the best solution but have a look @ https://github.com/lyft/scissors (im still using it in the app that i asked this question for) if you think  it is still use full i will add a sample in as an answer